# How to create a variable called at events in python

Tags: python, variables

In Python, I want to be able to create a new variable with a name close to another one in a loop at a certain runtime event
an example

```
for i in range (100):
   ###create a variable called var"i" = i
```

so after running the loop i would have a 100 new variables where
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
    var3 = 3
...

or maybe at certain event (lets say maybe a button pushed) 
a NEW string containing some info (say the contents of a QLineEdit text box) called stringX
so it doesn't overwrite the previous one

I searched around a little bit found "exec" but I would like some more explanation and to see if there is a way to do it without using "exec"

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Why do you need separate variable names? It sounds like you probably want to use an actual data structure, like a list or a dict instead.

Comment: Thanx this will probably solve my problem , I am very new to programming (and self-taught :D) still have got into the the "mind-frame of thr programmer"

Answer (score 1):

To store a sequence of values in Python, use a [list](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists). To initialize the list with a `for` loop, you have to initialize the variable to be an empty list:

```
sequence = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    sequence.append(i**2)
print(sequence)
```

will print the list `[1, 4, 9, 16, ..., 10000]`.

This is essentially a sequence of 100 variables: `sequence[0]`, `sequence[1]`, etc.

Also note that `range(1, 101)` itself produces a list-like generator.